# MongoDB MapReduce Error in map function when accessing nested array: TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a large data structure in `mongodb` that looks like the following:

```
datastructure = {
    "id": "id",
    "UpperLevel": [{
        "LowerLevel": [{
            "Name": "Name1",
            "Value": "Value1",
            "Flag": "Flag1"
        }, {
            "Name": "Name2",
            "Value": "Value2",
            "Flag": "Flag2"
        }, {
            "Name": "Name3",
            "Value": "Value3",
            "Flag": "Flag3"
        }, {
            "Name": "Name4",
            "Value": "Value4",
            "Flag": "Flag4"
        }]
    },
    "LowerLevel": [{
        "Name": "Name1",
        "Value": "Value1",
        "Flag": "Flag1"
    }, {
        "Name": "Name2",
        "Value": "Value2",
        "Flag": "Flag2"
    }, {
        "Name": "Name3",
        "Value": "Value3",
        "Flag": "Flag3"
    }, {
        "Name": "Name4",
        "Value": "Value4",
        "Flag": "Flag4"
    }]
  }]
}
```

This is just pseudo but I think you get the point. I now need only the values of each item of the lower level with associated name. What I am trying to do is I think explained better with the `mapFunction` of my `mapReduce` routine:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.UpperLevel.length; i++) {
    emit(this.id, {
        name1: parseFloat(this.UpperLevel[i].LowerLevel[0].Value),
        name2: parseFloat(this.UpperLevel[i].LowerLevel[1].Value),
        name3: parseFloat(this.UpperLevel[i].LowerLevel[2].Value),
        name4: parseFloat(this.UpperLevel[i].LowerLevel[3].Value
        }));
    }
}
```

My reduce function is just a dummy function since I got what I wanted.

```
var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {
    return Temp = {
    Data: values
    }
}
```

This works great for small collections but when I use it for large one(30GiB) I get `ExceptionCode 16722` and the error message:

```
Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Value'
of undefined
at _funcs1(_funcs1: 9: 77) near '.LowerLevel[3].Value);        
emit(key, value '
```

I know that this sometimes happens when the return value of your `reduce` function is not matching the value of your `map` function but that cannot be my problem here, can it?

Comment: This Error should be self explanatory as you are referencing a property of an object from an array where that array element has returned 'undefined'. I note that your 'LowerLevel' elements are all "hard coded" to the index values of 1 through 3. If you intend to get the "last three values" or "possible elements of index 1 - 3" then you should use `.slice()` instead, and build the object response.

Comment: But why does it work for smaller collections. The element cannot be undefined since the data in the collections are identical. One is just much larger than the other one.

Comment: Nothing to do with "collection size". One document in the data does not have "four" ( n + 1 ) array elements. Therefore the error.

Comment: This is impossible. The data is parsed before added to the collection and if i extract the whole lower-level objects like name1 : this.UpperLevel[i].LowerLevel[3] . It works.

Comment: Are you still missing that closing bracket in your code then?

Comment: Ok. You were right all along. I have to talk to the people about their parser. It did a bad job after about 10000 documents. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was with our parser. Nothing specific to mapreduce or mongodb.